# Dynamically create div with {#each} in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to dynamically create a 5 divs with a li using {each} in Svelte.

The code below renders the divs and lis but runs the calculate only once and hence gives the same result on each div/li:

```
let price;
let numberOfYears = 5;

function calculate() {
        price = price * 1.04;
    }

<form action="">
<label for="price">Price: </label>
<input type="number" bind:value={price} id="price" name="price" />
<button class="calculate" on:click={calculate}>Calculate</button>

{#each { length: numberOfYears } as _, i}
    <div style="float: left; width: 19%; border: 1px solid #000000;">
        <h2>Year 1</h2>
        {calculate()}
        <ul>
            <li>{price}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
{/each}
```

What I'm after is 5 years with incremental price (price * 1.04)

Comment: Btw, `float` is intended for something like placing images in text flow, not for "regular" layouts.

Comment: Also, placing styles in a `<style>` tag is preferred, as everything inside a component is scoped to that component, so it is easy to not affect anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Svelte is intended to be declarative, so you should not modify state in `{#each}`, instead your data array should contain the fully calculated results (or at least be independent from a shared mutable state).

So declare an array, e.g. `prices` and set that in `calculate()`, then use its items in the `each`.

E.g. something like this:

```js
let prices = [];
function calculate() {
    prices = new Array(numberOfYears).fill(price).map((p, i) => p * 1.04**i)
}
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/13f61ea2289348ec8770fafa2c450333?version=3.49.0)

You could also use a reactive statement (`$:`) to automatically calculate the values whenever a used variable (`price`/`numberOfYears`) changes;

```js
let price = null;
let numberOfYears = 5;

$: prices = price == null ?
   [] : new Array(numberOfYears).fill(price).map((p, i) => p * 1.04**i);
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/31d1226e56684057aabdf484790bf133?version=3.49.0)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach would be to use old fashioned mathematics to calculate your rates instead.

```html
<script>
    let numberOfYears = 5;
    let price = 1;
    let rate = 1.04;
    $: calculate = year => price*Math.pow(rate,year);
</script>

<input type="number" bind:value={numberOfYears} >
<input type="number" bind:value={price} >
<input type="number" bind:value={rate} step=".01">

{#each { length: numberOfYears } as _, i}
    <div>
        <h2>Year {i}</h2>
        <p>{calculate(i)}</p>
    </div>
{/each}
```

here the `calculate` function is reactive, so it will generate a new function whenever price or rate changes.  You could also write it directly in your brackets or use a `{@const}` to inline it more:

```html
{#each { length: numberOfYears } as _, i}
    {@const intrest = price*Math.pow(rate,i)}
    <div>
        <h2>Year {i}</h2>
        <!-- with @const -->
        <p>{intrest}</p>
        <!-- formula directly in the markup -->
        <p>{price*Math.pow(rate,i)}</p>
    </div>
{/each}
```

*note that my maths might be a bit off, make sure to use the correct formula*

Comment: Math should be correct, I just independently was simplifying my example and thought of doing it this way as well, though I ended up using `**` instead of `Math.pow`. +1